# bash function with third arg is an array

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a bash function that does the following:

- If there is no 3rd argument, run a command.
- If there is a third argument, take every argument from the third one and run a command.

The problem I have is the last bit of the command `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` in the `else` statement that I don't want to pass in all the time if I have multiple parameters.

```sh
An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM]
// that means I need to pass in --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Is there a way to tell bash that: hey, take all the args from the 3rd one, then add the `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` after? Like in JavaScript I can do this:

```js
function allTogetherNow(a, b, ...c) {
  console.log(`${a}, ${b}, ${c}. Can I have a little more?`);
}

allTogetherNow('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
```

Here's my function:

```sh
cloudformation_create() {
    if [ -z "$3" ]; then
        aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name "$1" --template-body file://"$2" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
    else
        aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name "$1" --template-body file://"$2" --parameters "${@:3}" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
    fi
}
```

And the 3rd and so on parameters look like this if I don't use a bash function:

```sh
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name MY_STACK_NAME --template-body file://MY_FILE_NAME --parameters ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=TestKey ParameterKey=SubnetIDs,ParameterValue=SubnetID1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

> Update 22 May 2019:

Following Dennis Williamson's answer below. I've tried:

- Passing the parameters in the AWS way:

```sh
cloudformation_create STACK_NAME FILE_NAME ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=TestKey ParameterKey=SubnetIDs,ParameterValue=SubnetID1
```

Got error:

```sh
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameters: [...] must have values
```

- Pass in as a string:

```sh
cloudformation_create STACK_NAME FILE_NAME "ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=TestKey ParameterKey=SubnetIDs,ParameterValue=SubnetID1"
```

Got error:

```sh
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: ParameterValue for ... is required
```

- Pass in without `ParameterKey` and `ParameterValue`:

```sh
cloudformation_create STACK_NAME FILE_NAME KeyPairName=TestKey SubnetIDs=SubnetID1
```

Got error:

```sh
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Parameters[0]: "PARAM_NAME", must be one of: ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue, ResolvedValue
// list of all the params with the above error
```

- Pass in without `ParameterKey` and `ParameterValue` and as a string. Got error:

```sh
arameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Parameters[0]: "PARAM_NAME", must be one of: ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue, ResolvedValue
```

**I tried Alex Harvey's answer** and got this:

```sh
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: unsupported structure.
```

Comment: That function looks good to me. How is it not working?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson it needs the `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` at the end. For some reason, my bash function takes all the args but doesn't add the capability at the end.

Comment: I don't think it's your function that's consuming that last option and its argument. I think it may be the malformed argument to `--parameters` that's causing that argument to consume the other. See my answer.

Comment: I changed to comma and got this error:
```bash
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Parameters[0]: "PARAM_NAME", must be one of: ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue, ResolvedValue
```

Comment: What happens when you use your Bash function (just below "Here's my function:" above) which uses "${@:3}" (instead of the asterisk)?

Comment: I got that error but I've realised my mistake now. Thank you. @DennisWilliamson.

Comment: We don't add "solved" to question titles on Stack Overflow. Please post your solution as an answer. You can even mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thank you. I was trying to save you (and others) time because I can only mark my own answer as "correct answer" tomorrow.

Comment: But you can (and should) post it today, if possible.

Comment: @Viet, fyi, the "unsupported structure" is because of a typo on my part ; I missed the "file://" bit. I've updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for your help.

I've realised the issue (and **my mistake**):

AWS returned the error with `Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM]` and my function has `[CAPABILITY_IAM]`.
Depends on the template with params related to creating IAM, `[CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM]` or `[CAPABILITY_IAM]` is required. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251580/when-do-i-need-to-have-capability-named-iam) helpful.

So in my case, the bash function is good, for the template I was trying to create, I need to pass in `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM`. I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Based on LeBlue's answer and a quick read of the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html), it looks like you need to build the argument to `--parameters` from the arguments to the function:

```bash
cloudformation_create () {
local IFS=,
local parameters="${*:3}"

#if block not shown
aws cloud_formation ... --parameters "$parameters" ...
```

this presumes that your function is called like this:

```
cloudformation_create foo bar baz=123 qux=456
```

that is, with the key, value pairs already formed.

The snippet above works by setting `IFS` to a comma. Using `$*` inside quotes causes the elements contained in it to be joined using the first character of `IFS`. If you need to make use of the word splitting features in another part of your function, you may want to save the current value of `IFS` before changing it then restore it after the joining assignment.

As a result, the expansion of `$parameters` will be `baz=123,qux=456`

Comment: I'm sorry. This doesn't work. I'll update my question with what I got from your code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that answers your question but maybe it will help you.

$# is the number of parameters.

$@ will include all parameters and you can pass that.

```
#!/bin/bash

foo()
{
    echo "params in foo: " $#
    echo "p1: " $1
    echo "p2: " $2
    echo "p3: " $3
}

echo "number of paramters: " $#

foo $@ 3   # pass params and add one to the end
```

**Call:**

```
./test.sh 1 2
```

**Output:**

```
number of paramters:  2
params in foo:  3
p1:  1
p2:  2
p3:  3
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for, I need something like this: `foo $1 $2 $3 $4 (and so on) then does: do $1 and $2 and do $3 $4 $5 then do the last bit`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the parameter expansion is wrong, as `--parameters` probably needs to have *one* argument.
Either quote all arguments to `cloudformation_create` that need to end up as value for the `--parameters` flag:

```
cloudformation_create "the-stack" "the-filename" "all the parameters"
```

or rewrite the function to *not* expand into multiple arguments with `"$*"` (merge every arg into one)

```
cloudformation_create () {
    ...
    else
        aws cloudformation ... --parameters "${*:3}" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
    fi
}
```

This will preserve all values as one string/argument, both will translate to:

```
aws cloudformation  ... --parameters "all other parameters" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

as opposed to your version:

```
aws cloudformation ... --parameters "all" "other" "parameters" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Comment: I think you may be close. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) indicate that the argument to `--parameters` is a comma-delimited list of `key=value` pairs.

Comment: I think you're close. Like @DennisWilliamson wrote above, the `--parameters` is a list. I've updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way:

```bash
cloudformation_create() {
  local stack_name=$1
  local template_body=$2
  shift 2 ; local parameters="$@"

  local command=(aws cloudformation create-stack 
    --stack-name "$stack_name"
    --template-body "file://$template_body")

  [ ! -z "$parameters" ] && \
    command+=(--parameters "$parameters")

  command+=(--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM)

  ${command[@]}
}
```

Note:

- calling `shift 2` results in `$3` being rotated to `$1` such that you can just use `$@` as normal.

Comment: You can do `shift 2`. Putting commands, options and arguments in variables is [discouraged](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).